# how to run an akka streaming app in argo and kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, akka, akka-stream, argo-workflows, argoproj

How can you run an akka streams application in argo and kubernetes, I found documentation about kubernetes and akka cluster, but I don't need an akka cluster, do I just need to run an ephemeral akka application with many actors; or is an akka cluster necessary?

Comment: You question does not sounds clear. What did you tried so far? What problems did you face? Akka-cluster and akka-streams are two orthogonal things solving two different kind of problems

Comment: @Ivan Kurchenko is about to design a stream flow and i need to know what could be the best option between argo or akka cluster and how to implement them; the problem is to do a streaming app with akka stream and run it on argo and kubernetes, and i don't know if is necesary akka cluster because the app is ephemere also how to execute it in argo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an Akka Stream app on Kubernetes in a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) just like you can run it locally when testing.

If you need your application to scale to many Pods and handle a lot of input, it may be helpful to use an Akka Cluster to better distribute the work.

Argo Workflows and Akka Streams serve similar purposes: both connect a series of steps to transform data. Argo Workflows connects containers, and Akka Streams connects actors.

Depending on your use case, it might make sense to have an Argo Workflows step that runs an Akka Streams app (which runs a while and then exits). But it might be simpler to write the whole series of steps as either just an Akka Streams app (which is then run on a Deployment) or just an Argo Workflow (made up of non-Akka Streams containers).

tl;dr - There are a variety of "right" ways to run an Akka Streams app in Argo and/or Kubernetes. The "best" choice depends on your use case. At the end of the day, you either drop your Akka Streams container in the `image` field of either a Kubernetes Deployment or an Argo Workflow.